# Files added to my Ruby Project when using RBENV

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rbenv

After installing RBEnv and rebuilding my ROR project, I now seem to have added many, many files to my project.  They are in /vendor/local, and appear to duplicate what you would normally find in /Library/Ruby/Gems.

My project will not run without these files present (I get the message `Could not find rake-0.9.2.2 in any of the sources`.

I had difficulties with my RBEnv installation.  I have what I suspect are other issues (like I have to `bundle exec rails` instead of just running `rails`).  I suspect that I have done something wrong and should not have these files in my project. What I'd like to know is:

1) Should these files be there?

2) How best to fix this (if this is not how it is supposed to work)?

3) If the best approach is to start over and reinstall rbenv, how do I clear it all out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is true that using RBENV will end up putting copies of your gems in the project's /vendor/local folder.  This is to remove any dependencies on your base gem set.  These files need not be part of your source repository, as long as your 'gemfile' and your '.rbenv-version' file are included in the repository.

Another price you pay for using rbenv is that you must `bundle exec rails <command>` and `bundle exec rake <command>` from here on in.